# Batch delete part of filename in mac Terminal

Tags: macos, rename

I have a few files named filename_xxhdpi.png and I want to remove the "_xxhdpi" part of the filename, how can I do this in Mac terminal?

Also, how can I do an Apple Script that targets a specific folder to change names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With [renme](/questions/tagged/renme) :

```
rename 's/_xxhdpi//' *
```

Ensure you have the perl's rename one